# Reading files from remote directory

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, download

I'm developing a windows phone application, what I want to is to read all file names which reside in remote directory on the server and after that download the chosen ones to the application resources or content, file types are kml, and afterwards use this downloaded files in my application. The only examples on web show how to download exact file but this doesn't work in my case I need to get a list of files in Directory. I'm new to WP and can't find a solution

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you split your task into chunks. This makes it easyer for you to find samples, and you can post concrete questions if you get stuck:

- A Remote Server API to return all FileNames from a directory. (eg. JSON / XML List)
- A Remote API to download a file by its fileName
- A UI in your WP where you list all available Files with checkboxes to select certain files
- A WP Class that starts a download for the selected Files (eg. Queue all selected filenames and start Background Transfer)

with these bits you are able to search and ask about certain specific problems. OK?